# Outlook 2003: authentication before sending doesn’t work (probably command sequence problem)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, smtp

i'm having problems with outlook 2003 + smtp authentication. although it's set in outlook, my mailserver won't relay - which means, outlook is trying to mail BEFORE authenticating.

i've tried the same with thunderbird, auth + sending works without problems.

so it definately must be something in outlook and it's command-sequence - what could be wrong?

thx

Answer (score 0):

In Advance settings you should require authentication before sending...

Comment: i already did.
i checkded the server logs and outlook is NOT sending the auth-sequence (base64 encoded password ..) :/
thunderbird does.